# How to update field on Firestore using RecyclerView with onClick?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `RecyclerView` using `Firestore Adapters`. I have a button on my `itemView`. I am trying to make it so that when the button is pressed, it will change the boolean field `done` from false to true. I am struggling to understand how to tie those two together.

Currently, I am able to read when which position inside of the `RecyclerView` with an interface and display it on my `Log`. But that's pretty much it. Here is my code:

**The interface:**

```
public interface OnListAdminClick {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

**My Adapter:**

```
public class DonorAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<DonorModel, DonorAdapter.DonorViewHolder> {

private OnListAdminClick onListAdminClick;

public DonorAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<DonorModel> options, OnListAdminClick onListAdminClick) {
    super(options);
    this.onListAdminClick = onListAdminClick;
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DonorAdapter.DonorViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DonorModel model) {
    holder.rank.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
    holder.donorName.setText(model.getDonorName());
    holder.donorEmail.setText(model.getDonorEmail());
    holder.hospitalName.setText(model.getHospitalName());
    holder.bookingTime.setText(model.getTime());
    holder.status.setText(model.isDone() + "");
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DonorAdapter.DonorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_adminview_single, parent, false);
    return new DonorViewHolder(view);
}

public class DonorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView rank;
    TextView donorName;
    TextView donorEmail;
    TextView hospitalName;
    TextView bookingTime;
    TextView status;
    Button done_btn;

    public DonorViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        rank = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adminview_position);
        donorName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_username);
        donorEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_email);
        hospitalName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_hospital_name);
        bookingTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_booking_time);
        status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_booking);
        done_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.done_btn);

        done_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         onListAdminClick.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
}
```

**Defining the onItemClick on my Main:**

```
        adapter = new DonorAdapter(options, new OnListAdminClick() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            Log.d("ITEM_CLICK", "Clicked the item: " + position);

        }
    });
```

**Lastly my Firestore:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your adapter class that you pass to the onItemClick() method the position, which is not very helpful as it represents only the position of the clicked item in the RecyclerView. However, passing the "donorUID" will help you solve the problem. This can be done very easily, bypassing the "donorUID" value to the DonorViewHolder's constructor. Now the declaration of your interface should look like this:

```
public interface OnListAdminClick {
    void onItemClick(int donorUID);
}
```

And inside your activity, you can update the "done" property to true using the following lines of code:

```
adapter = new DonorAdapter(options, new OnListAdminClick() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int donorUID) {
        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference bookingRef = rootRef.collection("UserBooking").document(donorUID).collection("Booking");
        Query donorUidQuery = bookingRef.whereEqualTo("donorUID", donorUID);
        donorUidQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        document.getReference().update("done", true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try this out! but one question, is the `donorUID` supposed to be in `int`?

Comment: Yes, it can be also an int. However, if you use that id as a document id, it will be a String.

Comment: I am not sure how to go about passing `donorUID` to the `DonorViewHolder`'s constructor. But, if I tried it this way, does it still work the same? https://imgur.com/wP6C9ei

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how one pass the `donorUID` to the `DonorViewHolder`

Comment: Yes, having the Donor object, you can get the donorUID and pass it to the constructor. That way you can use the donorUID in the DonorViewHolder class.

Comment: it gives me an error when I tried it this way https://imgur.com/a/yfOcGcH

Comment: Change the second parameter in the constructor to be of type String and **not** DonorModel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226744/discussion-between-scrin-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Have you tried what I wrote in my last comment?

Comment: I have! but now I am a bit puzzled as to what to pass the `String donorUID` bit when returning `DonorViewHolder()` inside of `onCreateViewHolder`

Comment: `return new DonorViewHolder(view, model.getDonorUID());` this is what  I have done so far

Comment: Yes, and once you pass that donorUID, use it in your DonorViewHolder class, that's it.

Comment: hey, I have decided to put the `onClick` to `onBindViewHolder` for easier reach. and it works! But hey, how do I remove the item from the `RecyclerView` once the button has been clicked?

Comment: Basically, this is another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. It's beyond the scope of this question. So please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I did, but it got bad rep. I have tried the solution that was "identical" to the problem that I faced but to no avail. Here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547629/how-do-i-remove-item-from-recyclerview-using-firestore-adapter

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, you can check [this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) out.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't. But, I'll give it a read and see what I can do. Can I hit you back again if I don't understand certain keywords? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, but the best solution is to add a question here on Stackoverflow. I read almost all Firebase questions.

Comment: thank you so much for your effort in helping the community, especially people newbie like me. I appreciate it greatly!